# React) Token and cookie are passed locallhost:3000, but displayed as undefined on the deployed server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, cookies, jwt, token

I am using front server through Ngingx. The server address is in the form of http://123.456.78.90

In localhost:3000, when sending a request, the token(JWT) is included in the header and sent successfully, but when the request is sent from the currently deployed server, the token is displayed as undefined

what's the problem

Below is the logic of storing token in header on login and including token in header on request, And the frontend Nginx conf

//API and Token

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});

const setAuthHeader = token => {
  apiInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
};

export { apiInstance, setAuthHeader };
```

//Logun module

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { apiInstance, setAuthHeader } from '../../util/api';
import { fetchUserInfo } from './userInfo';

export const __postLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  'postLogin',
  async (data, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await apiInstance.post('api/login', data);
      console.log(response);
      const token = response?.headers?.authorization;
      setAuthHeader(token);
      // Cookies.set('token', token, {
      //   sameSite: 'lax',
      //   secure: true,
      // });
      Cookies.set('token', token);
      console.log(token);
      await thunkAPI.dispatch(fetchUserInfo()).unwrap();
      const userInfoResponse = await apiInstance.get('/api/me');
      console.log(userInfoResponse);
      alert(`안녕하세요 ${userInfoResponse.data.name} 님`);
      const role = userInfoResponse.data.role;
      const loginResult = {
        response: response?.data.message,
        role: role,
      };
      return loginResult;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error.response.data.message);
      throw error;
    }
  }
);

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

const postLogin = createSlice({
  name: 'postLogin',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(__postLogin.pending, state => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(__postLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(__postLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default postLogin;
```

//request with token as header

```
export const fetchUserInfo = createAsyncThunk(
  'userInfo/fetchUserInfo',
  async () => {
    try {
      const getCookie = Cookies.get('token');
      setAuthHeader(getCookie);
      const userInfoResponse = await apiInstance.get('/api/me');
      return userInfoResponse.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

const userInfoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userInfo',
  initialState: {
    data: null,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUserInfo.pending, state => {
        state.loading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserInfo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.data = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserInfo.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

export const { reducer: userInfoReducer } = userInfoSlice;
export default userInfoSlice.reducer;
```

//Nginx conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /home/core/build;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```